# Not able to run project after upgrading project from angular 4 to 6

Tags: angular, npm

I upgraded my angular 4 project to angular 6.

I am facing one Error while running the project.

I have searched for similar questions but I didn't get a satisfactory answer.

```
 OpaqueToken is not a constructor.
```

Here I attache my package.json.

{

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/upgrade": "6.1.9",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "angular-pipes": "^6.5.3",
    "angular-sweetalert": "^1.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-meta": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-slugify": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-vs-checklist": "0.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-sweetalert2": "^0.2.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },


}
```

Comment: There is an update guide on the angular.io : https://update.angular.io/ . Did you follow the suggested steps by this guide ?

Comment: Show us the full error

Comment: `meta.module.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: core_1.OpaqueToken is not a constructor` @PrathapG

Comment: Added package.json @PrathapG

Comment: OpaqueToken is deprecated in newer versions of Angular. You will need to use the InjectionToken class https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolve the problem with updating my ng2-meta@2.0.3
 package which is used OpaqueToken. Maybe Which is not compatible in angular 6.

```
npm install ng2-meta@5.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

> InjectionToken

instead of

> OpaqueToken

Ex :-

```
// export const HTTP_FACTORY = new OpaqueToken("Http implementationfactory");

export const HTTP_FACTORY = new InjectionToken<HttpFactory>("Http implementation factory");
```

Comment: I am not using OpaqueToken anywhere in my project.
I got error in meta.module.js.
`meta.module.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: core_1.OpaqueToken is not a constructor` 
@PrathapG

Comment: did you upgrade all the packages?

Comment: OpaqueToken is deprecated in newer versions of Angular. You will need to use the InjectionToken class https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken